# Can't use `all()` with `getList()` in Restangular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, rest, restangular

I hope to access `trips/list_by_user` using Restangular..

I found this doesn't work..

```
Restangular.all('trips').getList('list_by_user')
```

But this works well..

```
Restangular.one('trips', 'list_by_user').getList()
```

I think `all` maybe a better way because I want a list instead of an element.. Does anyone have ideas about why `getList` can't be chained with `all`? Or is there a better way to write this request?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way. This works well

```
Restangular.all('trips').all('list_by_user').getList()
```